# C# How to call method from another class

Tags: c#, computer-science

I'm beginner with C# I need little help how to call method from one Class to another class. Since C# is strongly typed language I found it difficult to navigate through classes, methods etc.
I want to take 'GetSalesRevenue() - Class Salesman' and use it at departments 'GetRevenue() - Class Departments ';
This is my first attempt with C# OOP. Any help is appreciated!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;


namespace EmployeeDepartment
{
    class Departments
    {
        public Departments(string[] developers, string[] salesman)
        {
            Developers = developers;
            Salesman = salesman;
        }

        public string[] Developers { get; set; }
        public string[] Salesman { get; set; }
        public void GetRevenue(Salesman value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sum of revenus from All salesmen");
        }

        public void GetSkillset()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Print all skills from the developers in the deparment");
        }
    }

}




using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace EmployeeDepartment
{
    class Salesman : Employee
    {

        public Salesman(string name, string surname, int age, int salary, int salesrevenue, int salarysalesman) : base(name, surname, age, salary)
        {
            SalesRevenue = salesrevenue;
            SalarySalesman = salarysalesman;

        }
        private double SalesRevenue { get; set; }
        public double SalarySalesman { get; set; } = 400;

        // Salary is default 400 and Role is default Sales

        public double AddRevenue(double addRevenue)
        {
           return SalesRevenue += addRevenue;
        }
        public double GetSalesRevenue()
        {
            return SalesRevenue;
        }
        public double GetSalary(double plus)
        {
            return (SalesRevenue / 10) * 100;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I am confused. _GetSalesRevenue_ should return the total SalesRevenue from all Salesman belonging to that department? Where do you store the list of Salesman for that department? The two arrays contains strings not full Salesman instances

Comment: A very common miss of truly beginner c# programmers. While making sure to expose your methods as public, You didn't did it for your classes. Just add public to your classes.

Comment: Steve I was just creating the methods and I put return just to not get error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for something like this:

```
class Departments
{
    public Departments(string[] developers, string[] salesman)
    {
        Developers = developers;
        Salesman = salesman;
    }

    public string[] Developers { get; set; }
    public string[] Salesman { get; set; }
    
    public void GetRevenue(Salesman salesman)
    {
        double revenue = salesman.GetSalesRevenue();
        Console.WriteLine($"Sum of revenus from All salesmen: {revenue}" );
    }

    public void GetSkillset()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Print all skills from the developers in the deparment");
    }
}
```